# Error: You don't have permission to access that port

Tags: django

I have django application running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. All of a sudden I started getting below error while running server.

```
$ python manage.py runserver localhost:9000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 16, 2020 - 01:07:25
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'alphaslate.settings'
Starting development server at http://localhost:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
**Error: You don't have permission to access that port.**
```

Before this error, I updated to ubuntu.base through livepatch.
Please suggest how can I resolve this error or uninstall the latest livepatch.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another port for your django development server port to running.

for example

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:18080
```

Comment: not helped. same issue. 
```$ python manage.py runserver localhost:18080
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 16, 2020 - 10:16:00
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'alphaslate.settings'
Starting development server at http://localhost:18080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: You don't have permission to access that port.
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in a particular git branch only. I am still not sure what is wrong with it. As of now, I created new branch and it is working fine.